# Executar um arquivo .R dentro de outro código em R

Tags: r, makefile

Tenho um código que lê os arquivos XML que estão em uma pasta de rede corporativa, e gera um arquivo `.RData`. Tenho outros códigos que geram diferentes relatórios para os diferentes setores, usando como base o `RData`. O meu problema é: esses arquivos XML são atualizados com frequências diversas e nem sempre consigo saber quando foi realizada a última atualização. Gostaria de saber se há alguma função que execute este outro código (que gera o `RData`) sempre que gerar um relatório, justamente para evitar um arquivo RData baseado nos XML desatualizados e ter que ficar executando o outro código manualmente toda vez que um novo relatório for solicitado.
PS: Sei que posso inserir o código que leia o XML dentro do código do relatório, mas não o faço para evitar que o relatório fique muito extenso .

Edit: o script `leiturapastaDIPR.R` gera o arquivo `DIPRConsolidado.RData`.O RData é uma lista com 5 elementos e cada um deles é um Data Frame. Depois esse RData é carregado no RMarkDown `markdown.RMD` que gera o PDF do relatório. Se precisar de mais alguma informação sá avisar!

Comment: Você pode utilizar a função `source()`, mas o script sera lido toda vez, mesmo se o XLM não mudou. Uma outra solução mais elegante seria de criar um `makefile` no qual ele irá executar esse script R somente quando o XLM muda. Se você der mais informações sobre os nomes dos scripts, dados e a ordem de execução, podemos ajudar na construção do `makefile`.

Comment: O `source()` nem seria em si um problema, mas pelo que percebi esse `makefile` parece ser uma solução mais elegante!

Comment: Isso, `source()` não é um problema mas uma solução não eficiente (em questão de tempo perdido repetindo análises que já foram feitas). Vou postar aqui como resposta um `makefile` básico que servirá de exemplo para o seu problema.

Answer (score 1):

`Makefile` funciona como uma cadeia de regras onde você deve determinar o *target* que é geralmente o objeto que deseja criar (nesse caso um arquivo pdf), as *dependecias* deste *target* que são necessárias para cria-la, e finalmente a *receita* que é o comando utilizado para criar o *target*. Aqui vai um padrão:

```
target: depencia1
    receita
```

No exemplo acima, se a `dependência1` não está atualizada, o `makefile` irá rodar a `receita` para então criar o `target`.

#### Exemplo

Considerando que o nome do arquivo do relatório que você quer criar é `relatorio.Rmd` que irá gerar o pdf `relatorio.pdf`. Para criar o relatório você precisa 'chamar' R e renderizar o documento com o pacote `rmarkdown`.

Além disso, você pode criar uma cadeia de depencias. No seu caso, a renderização do seu documento depende se os dados de análise (`.Rdata`) estão atualizados, que este depende se os dados `.XLM` estão atualizados. Desta forma o seu `makefile` seria mais ou menos assim:

```
# exemplo de makefile

# aqui o pdf do relatorio depende do script .Rmd para cria-lo e também dos dados
# (se um desses dois não estão atualizados, ele vai rodar a receita)
relatorio.pdf: relatorio.Rmd DIPRConsolidado.RData
    Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('relatorio.Rmd')"

# como é uma cadeia, na etapa anterior o makefile testou se o .Rdata é atualizado,
# mas este depende do script .R e dos dados .XLM. Se um desses dois não estiver atualizado,
# ele ira rodar a receita abaixo
DIPRConsolidado.RData: leiturapastaDIPR.R dados.XLM
    Rscript leiturapastaDIPR.R
```

Você deve salvar esse script com o nome `makefile` e quando você quer chama-lo, você ira escrever `make` no terminal.

`makefile` não é a linguagem mais simples e lógica no primeiro contato, mas é uma ferramenta fundamental para garantir a reprodutibilidade de um projeto.